# A Question about a $U(1)_{B-L}$

Tags: symmetry, standard-model, group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics

I know I can write the QCD lagrangian like this:

$$ \mathcal{L} = (i\bar{q}_{R} \gamma_{\mu}\partial_{\mu} {q}_{R} + i\bar{q}_{L}\gamma_{\mu}\partial_{\mu} {q}_{L}) +  \text{other terms} $$

When written this way we say it is invariant under $SU(3)_{R}\times SU(3)_{L} \times U(1) \times U(1)$.

But in a book, "Stefan Scherer & Matthias Schindler - A Primer for Chiral Pertubation Theory", it says: $SU(3)_{R}\times SU(3)_{L} \times U(1)_{B-L}$.

Why that?

Comment: "In a book" is a useless reference. If you are citing something, *tell us what*. Also, whoever writes down $\mathrm{U}(1)_{B-L}$ should explain what is meant by that.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: The book is: "Stefan Scherer & Matthias Schindler - A Primer for Chiral Pertubation Theory"

Comment: You should *edit* such information into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find any reference to $U(1)_{B-L}$ in the book mentioned. The $L$ here refers to lepton number, and it's suspicious that this should arise in a book on QCD.

This aside, what symmetries does the QCD Lagrangian have? In the case that we have $N$ flavours of massless quark, we are free to rotate the left-handed quarks amongst themselves (in flavour space) and the right-handed quarks amongst themselves *independently*. This leads to the global symmetry:

$$ U(N) \times U(N) $$

At the level of the algebra, this symmetry can also be written

$$ SU(N)_L \times SU(N)_R \times U(1)_L \times U(1)_R$$

where the subscripts indicate whether the symmetry acts on the left- or right-handed quarks. Instead of independently rotating left or right, sometimes it can be useful to consider rephasing left and right *by the same amount*, or rephasing them by *opposite amounts*. These are referred to as vector and axial symmetries, respectively. One can show that any rephasing of just left, or just right, can be achieved by a combination of axial and vector rephasings. So
$$ U(1)_L \times U(1)_R = U(1)_V \times U(1)_A$$

Now for the punchline. In the quantum theory, the axial symmetry $U(1)_A$ is [**anomalous**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_(physics)). This means that it is not a symmetry quantum mechanically, despite being a symmetry classically. So the symmetry group of massless QCD as a quantum theory is:

$$ SU(N)_L \times SU(N)_R \times U(1)_V$$

One can check that a simultaneous rephasing of all quark flavours and chiralities by the same amount is precisely the symmetry corresponding to baryon number. So we can also write $U(1)_V = U(1)_B$. This is almost the end of the story, but we haven't yet explained why $U(1)_{B-L}$ should appear. It turns out that when we embed QCD into the standard model, and couple the quarks to the weak and hypercharge gauge bosons as well as the gluon, $U(1)_B$ is *also anomalous*. The same is true of $U(1)_L$, the symmetry that corresponds to rephasing all leptons simultaneously by the same amount. The only $U(1)$ global symmetry that survives in the quantum theory of the standard model is $B - L$, the symmetry corresponding to rotating all quarks by the same amount, and all leptons by the opposite amount.

Answer (score 2):

I searched through the whole book and didn't find a single instance of "$U(1)_{B-L}$", so a page number reference would be helpful. But for the purposes of pure QCD, $U(1)_V$ is the same as $U(1)_B$, because all quarks carry the same baryon number, and that's the same as $U(1)_{B-L}$ since nothing carries lepton number.

One might prefer to write $U(1)_{B-L}$ rather than $U(1)_V$ if one has the rest of the Standard Model in mind. If you include the other Standard Model gauge fields, it turns out that $U(1)_V$ is anomalous, and $U(1)_L$ is anomalous as well; the unique non-anomalous combination is $U(1)_{B-L}$. This is nice because it gives us an absolutely conserved quantity, as well as a symmetry that may be gauged.

That still doesn't fully explain it, because if they were only going to write down symmetries that were non-anomalous in the SM, they shouldn't have written down $SU(3)_L \times SU(3)_R$ either, since this symmetry is anomalous as well. I suspect they were just writing out of habit without looking too closely at what they were doing.